# SOAP or REST - when there is single client & multiple service providers + contract

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, architecture

We are using SOAP based web services to let end user schedule service appointments. Our portal is WebService client & we have a number of Vendors(who are spread across the globe in various timezones) who are building Webservice Server operations.
We are thinking to build it as a contract first SOAP based web services so that we have tight control(interface based e.g. date-time format should be standard xsd:dateTime etc.) over what can be sent & received as part of XML messages for possible success & error scenarios(via different error codes). We want to keep single client code for all the vendors. We would like to determine

1) Should we think about using RESTful web services?

2) Is there any way the vendors can use RESTful services also if they want at their end(by sticking to our WSDL contract) & we use SOAP at our end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a little bit about,

REST (Representation State Transfer) is an architecture style to develop webservice. In which data and functionality are considered as a resource and can be accessed via URI (Uniform Resource Indicator). It follows client server architecture and uses stateless protocol (usually HTTP). Typically in REST webserivces resources are acted upon by GET, PUT, POST,DELETE operation. Generally we use JSON to exchange data between client and server. It is light weight.

On the other hand SOAP (Simple Object Access Protocol) is a XML based mesaage protocol. Which is generally used on enterprise level to define their own interfacing and operations as services. It also follows REST architecture.
So basically, it is a RESTful webservice.

Now to answer your question,

It seems you are going to expose your webservice client on enterprise level. Which is going to be used by many vendors to implement their own webservice server.

So, it is perfect, you go with SOAP webservices.

1. You will define the skeleton of the webservice like Message formats, Operations, binding etc which is called WSDL. It is widely used standard and very easy to understand by any third party. Something called WADL is used for REST services also but it is not very user friendly.
2. The same contract (WSDL) will be used by your vendors to implement the webservice on their server in Top to Bottom approach using some API, for example JAX-WS.

This way you will have a tighter control over your operations, formats, security etc. in a single contract (WSDL).

Now if a vendor wants to use REST webservice instead of SOAP. You can build a JAVA proxy on top of your client. Which will convert your soap messages into REST to send/receive request/response to REST webservices. But you can not dictate your contract in this approach. Although, You can recommend vendors to build their own proxy to handle your SOAP webservice requests. This way your contract will be intact.

If you are going to expose your webservice client for small applications then it is alright to go with REST but if you are an enterprise and going to expand in future, you should go with SOAP for robust features and easy maintenance.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. As we have many vendors, so contract (WSDL) is central piece here. It will help avoid many recommendations, expectations from our side to be maintained separately.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: please do not consider this answer as really serious.

Well, I think question too abstract. Why do you asking it? Because you see yourself that currently everything is RESTful? Then you'r right. You can do any protocol. But if you will do REST with JSON instead of XML, everybody will thank you. And if you will use 40 years old technology for creating modern service, then probably not. Same for your contractors.

Answer (score 0):

The only advantage SOAP seems to have in your situation is that it is already implemented.

SOAP is a complex standard with unfriendly implementation and verbose implementation - i.e. hard to work with and maintain. Also note that you are not even using it "by the book" since your security is external to it and not using [ws-security](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html)

REST based interfaces would make your and your users' lives easier. I suggest you take a look at standards and tools like [swagger](http://swagger.io/) for building APIs.If you're running on premise you can take a look at API gateways like [tyk](https://tyk.io/) If you're running in the cloud you also take a look at [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/details/)